# Write data to next column in excel sheet (VB.NET) (What is wrong with this code?)

Tags: vb.net, excel, loops

How to do following using VB.NET,
1. write checkbox text to a column in excel sheet
2. clear checkboxes for new user entry
3. write new user entry to next column

I tried following code, but after writing first column, the program hangs. It does not show any exceptions. What is wrong with it?

```
Dim xl As New Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim st As Excel.Worksheet

wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("F:\open.xlsx")
st = wb.Worksheets(1)
Dim j As Integer

For j = 0 To 2
While j

If CheckBox1.Checked Then
st.Cells(1, j + 1).value = "1"
Else : st.Cells(1, j + 1).value = "N/A"
End If

If CheckBox2.Checked Then
st.Cells(2, j + 1).value = "1"
Else : st.Cells(2, j + 1).value = "N/A"
End If

If CheckBox3.Checked Then
st.Cells(3, j + 1).value = "1"
Else : st.Cells(3, j + 1).value = "N/A"
End If

CheckBox1.Checked() = False
CheckBox2.Checked() = False
CheckBox3.Checked() = False
ComboBox1.ResetText()

End While
Next

wb.Save()
xl.Quit()
xl = Nothing
wb = Nothing
st = Nothing
```

Help will be really appreciated. Not able to do this for last 2 hours. Desired result sheet is attached herewith

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a loop that never ends.

Look at these lines:

```
For j = 0 To 2
While j
'Other code
End While
Next
```

Your code should skip over the while when j =0 but once j = 1 it will repeat the while loop indefinitely. I'd recommend removing `while j` and `End while` and see if it works as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this but, it writes data to all three columns at once. I want to write checkbox data to column A with a click on next button, this click will also clear the checkboxes for new user entry. Now after new entry when user clicks next, the data should be written to column B of same excel sheet. This process continues.